# Invoking assemblies asynchronously

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, assemblies

I have a 'small' problem in one of my projects. I have to invoke 2 assemblies stored in

```
Byte()
```

I don't want them to be written to the disk, to do so, I do

```
        Sub Main()                
                Dim trd As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf LodFile1)
                trd.IsBackground = True
                trd.Start()
                Dim resourceManager As New Resources.ResourceManager("Files", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
                Dim [Bin2] As Byte() = DirectCast(resourceManager.GetObject("File2"), Byte())
                resourceManager.ReleaseAllResources()
                Dim a2 = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load([Bin2])
                Dim m2 As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = a2.EntryPoint
                Dim o2 As Object = a2.CreateInstance(m2.Name)
                m2.Invoke(o2, New Object() {New String() {"1"}})
        End Sub
        Sub LodFile1()
                Dim resourceManager As New Resources.ResourceManager("Files", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
                Dim [Bin1] As Byte() = DirectCast(resourceManager.GetObject("File1"), Byte())
                resourceManager.ReleaseAllResources()
                Dim a1 = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load([Bin1])
                Dim m1 As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = a1.EntryPoint
                Dim o1 As Object = a1.CreateInstance(m1.Name)
                m1.Invoke(o1, New Object() {New String() {"1"}})
        End Sub
```

Yes, the two assemblies runs fine, the appear both, but when I close one, the three apps close(This one, and those that were loaded from byte()).

So, I am asking on how to run them separately.

Comment: This question makes little sense, you can't "close" an assembly.  There is otherwise little guarantee that the thread will be able to finish its job.  Once the Main() method is done, the program will terminate.  Regardless of what the thread is doing since you set its IsBackground property to True, allowing the CLR to abort it.

Comment: Knew about my error, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background threads are aborted when there are no foreground threads running.

Try: `trd.IsBackground = False`

Or even better: Just remove the line :)